# Настроить домен REACT + PHP

Tags: php, reactjs

Не могу понять, как настроить домен при разработки на React. Устанавливал, естественно, через *react-create-app* - `http://localhost:3000`.

Есть простенькая авторизация на PHP - работает на локальном сервере (`Open Server`). Но домены получаются разные, не проходит авторизация (точнее не сохраняется)

Кроссдоменные авторизации - это слишком для меня ) 
Может можно как-то настроить сам реакт (сервер), что бы он работал на том же домене что и PHP (код авторизации) ?

Comment: а в чём проблема на время разработки кроссдоменнить?

Answer (score 0):

Сервер из create-react-app вообще можно не использовать.
Когда вы делаете сборку npm run dev (npm run build), на выходе получается простой js файл.
Никто не мешает на php рендерить main шаблон в который вы подключите свой скрипт сборки, домен будет один авторизация через куки должна заработать.

Собственно если вы загляните в директорию сборки (у меня она называется /build) там есть файл index.html в который так же подключается js скрипт вашей сборки, примерно так же и должен выглядеть ваш шаблон на php.

Но нужно будет поправить конфиг вебпака, так-как сейчас к названию файла дописывается название версии и оно всегда разное, то есть чтобы после каждой сборки в php руками не проставлять правильную версию её лучше вообще убрать, чтобы имя скрипта было одно и тоже.
(Для кастомизации конфигов используйте команду eject)

Comment: Да, когда файл будет собран, он будет лежать допустим на домене PROD. И запросы его будут внутри домена. Но когда разрабатываю, получается что React на DEV, а php код на DEV_PHP. Два разных домена. (php авторизует юзера и кидает в сессию, но сразу же, получается, сбрасывает её, так как запрос с другого домена DEV ). Мне нужно именно во время разработки их подружить

Comment: Можно просто положить react проект в директорию с php-кодом (туда где статика лежит). И при разработке не использовать npm start, использовать npm run dev, каждый раз делать dev сборку (это самый простой вариант). А вообще можно переписать конфиг вебпака чтобы он мониторил изменения и пересобирал сборку сам, то есть вы не будете использовать сервер из create-react-app

Comment: я всё таки надеюсь найти более оптимальный вариант )

Comment: В сторону авторизации на  jwt токенах не смотрели? Это по моему самый правильный путь, вы не будете привязаны к домену

Comment: Да мне просто не понятно. Неужели это такой редкий кейс?... Ведь сайтов на php очень много. И соответственно привязка к php тоже. Т.е. че - переписывать код проекта, только лишь потому, что во время разработки разные домены?.. не может быть такого...

Comment: Возможно есть хак с файлом hosts, как-то похитрому настроить локальные домены. Самому интересно стало, похожая ситуация в проекте сейчас